# Error para guardar imágenes en bd carga el mismo valor para todos c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

Tengo un formulario que adjunto con una imagen para referencia, el programa me realiza el guardado de varias imágenes que en total son 15, en un campo de mi base de datos tipo image, pero el problema reside que al ejecutar el método, si guardo las 3 primeras imágenes a todas le asigna el mismo valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí pongo el código del método que me hace la obtención de los datos tipo byte.

```
 public byte[] Extraer_Byte(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1)
    {
        byte[] file = null;
        
            Stream mystream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mystream.CopyTo(ms);
                file = ms.ToArray();
            }
                    

        return file;
    }
```

Si solo trato de cargar 3 imágenes a todas me asigna el mismo valor.

```
private void btnGuardarPesSeis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
                    byte[] file1 = daoOdont.Extraer_Byte(openFileDialog1);
                    byte[] file2 = daoOdont.Extraer_Byte(openFileDialog1);
                    byte[] file3 = daoOdont.Extraer_Byte(openFileDialog1);

                    daoOdont.Guardar_Imagenes(file1,file2,file3,txtCodHisCliP1);                    
            }
                          
        }
```

La pregunta es si estoy realizando mal la asignación de los valores que causa que a todos me asigne el mismo valor, ya que al realizar la selección previamente la cargo uno a uno y posteriormente realizo la opción del guardado de acuerdo a la imagen que selecciono previamente, aquí pongo el código de cada uno de los botones para la selección de cada una de las imágenes

```
private void btupIm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Archivos png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Selección de Imagenes";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtIma1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }

    }

    private void btupIm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Archivos png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Selección de Imagenes";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtIma2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btupIm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Selección de Imagenes";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Archivos png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtIma3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes porque le pasas al método `Extraer_Byte`, la misma instancia de `openFileDialog1` que para ese momento tendrá el último archivo seleccionado.

Mi sugerencia es que cambies un poco el método `Extraer_Byte` para que reciba como parámetro la ubicación del archivo que almacenas en cada `txtIma??.Text`

```
//                           |  Cambia el parámetro
//                           V  
public byte[] Extraer_Byte(string archivoDeImagen)
{
    byte[] file = null;


    // Ten el cuenta el 'using' para mystream
    // |
    // |                     | así reemplazas la apertura del archivo que hacías
    // |                     | con openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
    // V                     V
    using (Stream mystream = File.OpenRead(archivoDeImagen))
    using (MemoryStream sm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mystream.CopyTo(ms);
        file = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return file;
}
```

Luego en el método para cargar las imágenes `btnGuardarPesSeis_Click` usas como argumentos los valores almacenados en cada `txtIma??.Text` como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
private void btnGuardarPesSeis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    //                                    | cambia 'openFileDialog1' por el
    //                                    | txtIma correspondiente
    //                                    V
    byte[] file1 = daoOdont.Extraer_Byte(txtIma1.Text);
    byte[] file2 = daoOdont.Extraer_Byte(txtIma2.Text);
    byte[] file3 = daoOdont.Extraer_Byte(txtIma3.Text);

    daoOdont.Guardar_Imagenes(file1,file2,file3,txtCodHisCliP1);                    
}
```

Recuerda hacer las validaciones necesarias y utilizar [try-catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) para proteger la aplicación de las posibles excepciones que se pueden generar al trabajar con archivos.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, un abrazo!